# Ethereum Block Synchronize delay

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, geth-debugging

I run the geth on my server. But after days, the block number is behind the network thousands. I restart, but no use.

I need remove the block and re-sync from the beginning. But later it's behind again. Anyone knows why and how to solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everyday thousands of blocks are being added to blockchain , so it is better to do a sync with the blockchain atleast once a day . There is no need to restart everytime, you can start from where you left but the network speed should be good as this makes a lot of difference.

Comment: My node keeps running. But it somehow will left behind the real netowrk

Comment: what is the output of eth.syncing for you?

Comment: what is the version of geth that you are using?